The app crashes during the SMS auto-verify call on Android 14 when I change the targetSdkVersion to 34
The app crashes during the SMS auto-verify call on Android 14 when I change the targetSdkVersion to 34. I want to change it to 34 to upload it to the play console.
Error logs:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(19989): Process: com.namp.zeon,
PID: 19989 E/AndroidRuntime(19989): java.lang.SecurityException:
com.namp.zeon: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively
for system broadcasts E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3087)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3071)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3054)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2996)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:5684)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1868)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1804)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1792)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:765)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
com.jaumard.smsautofill.SmsAutoFillPlugin$2.onSuccess(Unknown
Source:44) E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
com.jaumard.smsautofill.SmsAutoFillPlugin$2.onSuccess(Unknown
Source:2) E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(Unknown Source:25)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:257) E/AndroidRuntime(19989):
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:368) E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8839)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
Method) E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:572)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote
stack trace: E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiverWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:14900)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2570)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3005)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1387)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989): at
android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1299)
E/AndroidRuntime(19989):
Steps to reproduce Change the targetSdkVersion in build.gradle to 34.
use this plugin(sms_autofill: ^2.3.0) for sms auto fill.
Expected results It should fetch the OTP code from the message.
Actual results App crashes when moving to the verify otp screen.


you need to explicitly add the android:exported attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml for the BroadcastReceiver.
  <receiver
    android:name=".YourReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.MY_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

Or update
from (sms_autofill: ^2.3.0) to (sms_autofill: ^2.4.0)

Both the solution works, Thanks.
Can you explain why first works?

In Android 13 (API level 33) and above, including targetSdk 34, the Android system requires that you explicitly specify whether a BroadcastReceiver is exported or not exported in the app's manifest file. If you don't define either, you'll encounter the error
